# Python: Script to start Omxplayer from crontab

Tags: python, cron

I am trying to have cron run a python script that plays an MP3 file.

It sounded easy but I have been searching and struggling to find the correct solution and was hoping someone could steer me in the right direction.

This code below works fine when I connect via SSH into my headless Raspberry Pi:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# play mp3 from cron task
# Import moduals and functions


import os, sys

os.system('omxplayer -o local Lithium.mp3')



sys.exit()
```

But it does not work when cron is set to run every 5 minutes.

```
*/5 * * * * python /home/pi/music/mp3.py &>/dev/null
```

After searching around I seem to think it should be run as some sort of sub-process?
I have tried various bits of code such as `popen()` and `call()` to no avail.

Am I heading in the right direction with sub-processes and if so which one I should be looking to use, or is this not possible.

Comment: I don't know python, but I use this command invoked from a perl script `omxplayer /full/path/to/video> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &`

Comment: @kyle2k Did foibs comment answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

[$PATH](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html) is often not set in cron so use the full path and log err and out to resolve any issues:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/pi/music/mp3.py >/home/pi/music/mp3.log 2>&1
```

You can use `env` ([env](http://linux.die.net/man/1/env)) to check how your cron environment differs from the one configured for ssh.